# Unexpected token, expected. React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I cannot catch what is I missed?

> Error: "Unexpected token, expected ,"

Error gets in this part `value === ''`

The code:

```
    return {
        iteams: {
            todos: { 
                value === '' ? filteredTodos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id) 
                : value !== '' ? filteredSearchTodos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id) 
                : state.iteams.todos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
            },
            buttons: { 
                value === '' ? filteredButtons.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id) 
                : value !== '' ? filteredSearchButtons.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id) 
                : state.iteams.buttons.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id),   
            }
        },
        value: value,
        filter: filter,
        tempFilter: tempFilter
    };
```

Comment: javascript objects have a specific syntax - todos and buttons are objects - you probably just want `todos: value ===` etc

Comment: You may have a missing bracket elsewhere in the code. Your ternaries within ternaries are indented in a very confusing manner.
Also I agree with the removal of the picture. It doesn't help. If there is more relevant code you want to show, simply post more code.

Comment: To be fair i have no clue as what you are trying to do. What exactly do you want to have in the `todos` object ?

Comment: @MaxWolfen As some advice for the future, don't use nested ternaries. They are made of pure evil.

Answer (score 1):

it seems `todos` and `buttons` should be arrays of values - so you want to remove the `{}` for `todos` and `buttons`

```
        todos:  
            value === '' ? filteredTodos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id) 
            : value !== '' ? filteredSearchTodos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id) 
            : state.iteams.todos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
        ,
```

and same for `buttons:`

At the moment, your code is equivalent to

```
todos:{[1,2,3]}
```

which is not valid javascript

what you want is

```
todos:[1,2,3]
```